# Pandas melt dataframe while separating value columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
id  cost  val1  val1_avg  val1_tot  val2  val2_avg  val2_tot  val3  val3_avg  val3_tot  
1   5     29    24        45        15    18        78        25    32        56
```

Now I want to melt this dataframe on id and cost, such that I also separate value, avg value & total value for val1, val2, & val3. So finally I want to get below dataframe:

```
id  cost variable  value  value_avg  value_tot
1    5   val1      29     24         45
1    5   val3      15     18         78
1    5   val3      25     32         56
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```py
df.columns = [col.split('_')[1] + '_' + col.split('_')[0] if '_' in col else col for col in df.columns]

out = pd.wide_to_long(df, ["val", "avg_val", "tot_val"], i=["id", "cost"], j='variable').reset_index()
out['variable'] = 'val' + out['variable'].astype(str)

out.columns = [col.split('_')[1] + '_' + col.split('_')[0] if '_' in col else col for col in out.columns]
```

```
print(out)

   id  cost variable  val  val_avg  val_tot
0   1     5     val1   29       24       45
1   1     5     val2   15       18       78
2   1     5     val3   25       32       56
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
(df
 .set_index(['id', 'cost'])
 .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex
                              .from_arrays(zip_longest(*d.columns.str.split('(?=_)'),
                                                       fillvalue='')),
                            axis=1
                           ))
 .rename_axis(columns=('variable', None))
 .stack(0)
 .add_prefix('value')
 .reset_index()
)
```

Alternative with `melt`+`pivot`:

```
(df
 .melt(id_vars=['id', 'cost'])
 .assign(col=lambda d: 'value'+d['variable'].str.split('(?=_)').str[1].fillna(''),
         variable=lambda d: d['variable'].str.split('_').str[0],
        )
 .pivot(['id', 'cost', 'variable'], 'col', 'value')
 .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   id  cost variable  value  value_avg  value_tot
0   1     5     val1     29         24         45
1   1     5     val2     15         18         78
2   1     5     val3     25         32         56
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add `value` to the appropriate columns, before reshaping with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(pat = "val\d+$", 
                                    repl = lambda m:f"{m.group(0)}_value",
                                    regex = True)

(df
.pivot_longer(index = ['id', 'cost'], 
              names_to = ('variable', '.value'), 
              names_sep='_')
.rename(columns = {'avg':'value_avg', 'tot':'value_tot'})
)

   id  cost variable  value  value_avg  value_tot
0   1     5     val1     29         24         45
1   1     5     val2     15         18         78
2   1     5     val3     25         32         56
```

The `.value` is a placeholder that determines which part of the column label remains as a header (based on the split with `names_sep`).

Another option is to pass a list of regexes to `names_pattern` (this does not require you to rename the columns) :

```py
# using the original df, without any renaming
(df
.pivot_longer(index = ['id', 'cost'], 
              names_to = ('variable', 'drop1', 'drop2'), 
              values_to = ('value', 'value_avg', 'value_tot'), 
              names_pattern = ('val\d+$', 'avg$', 'tot$'))
.loc[:, ['id', 'cost', 'variable', 'value', 'value_avg', 'value_tot']]
)

   id  cost variable  value  value_avg  value_tot
0   1     5     val1     29         24         45
1   1     5     val2     15         18         78
2   1     5     val3     25         32         56
```